# Git conflict but no one line showing

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge-conflict

I have conflict on the GIT then i try merge code, but not showing what lines conflicting. my file and main branch source file is equal line by line..
[image]

Comment: It might be related to spaces. One of your developers might be spacing with tabs, and the other with spaces.

Comment: can i now merge forced without fixing it ?

Comment: or execution rights. If somehow on the way (file systems, `chmod`, ...) the file changed permissions from `rw-rw-rw-` to `rwxrwxrwx`, that might be a source, too.

Comment: @Yourchoice Yes, you can, but first investigate and tell us if that is the reason OR what Boldewyn has said?

Comment: It could be that the file no longer exists on the branch you are trying to merge into.  In other words, it could be a "tree" conflict, rather than a content conflict.

Comment: works changed file permisions :)